# How to find dominant color RGB using histograms?

Tags: python, image-processing, colors, histogram

I am currently developing a series of test code to explore different ways of processing image data, and one of my main topics is color extraction.

I have developed the following Python code, which, given an image, is capable of extracting its correspondent histograms with R, G and B values:

```
# Reading original image, in full color
img = mpimg.imread('/content/brandlogos/Images/14 (48).jpg')

# Displaying the image
imgplot = plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()

# Creating a tuple to select colors of each channel line
colors = ("r", "g", "b")
channel_ids = (0, 1, 2)

# Making an histogram with three lines, one for each color
# The X limit is 255, for RGB values
plt.xlim([0,256])
for channel_id, c in zip(channel_ids, colors):
  histogram, bin_edges = np.histogram(
      img[:, :, channel_id], bins = 256, range=(0,256)
  )
  plt.plot(bin_edges[0:-1], histogram, color=c )

# Displaying the histogram
plt.xlabel("Color Value")
plt.ylabel("Pixels")

plt.show()
```

Example:

[image: Code Result]

However, I now want to find the RGB value of the most dominant color, according to the histogram information.

Expected output: `(87, 74, 163)` (or something similar)

How would I go about finding the highest bin counts for the three color channels, combining them into a single color?

Comment: You need to build a 3D histogram for RGB values (joint histogram), not separate histograms for each channel (marginal histograms). Within the 3D histogram you could find the highest peak, you could find the peak with the most weight, or any number of other things. It depends on how you define “dominant color”.

Comment: By dominant color, I mean the R, G and B with the highest pixel counts.
For instance, if I find the peak in the histogram I presented above, I would get something very close to (87, 74, 163). This is what I intend to do programatically:
Find the "color value" peak for each of the three channels.

Comment: You cannot do this per channel. You need to use the joint histogram. The highest peak works well for images with mostly flat regions like your example, but not for natural images, where what we perceive as one color can be spread over many bins of the histogram. This is why I asked for your definition. Are all your images like the one in your example?

Comment: All of my images are of corporate logos. They vary greatly in detail and shapes but more often than not, are comprised of a solid color with text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can focus on the [`unique`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) colors in your image, and find the one with the highest count:

```py
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np

img = np.uint8(mpimg.imread('path/to/your/image.png') * 255)
img = np.reshape(img, (np.prod(img.shape[:2]), 3))
res = np.unique(img, axis=0, return_counts=True)
dom_color = res[0][np.argmax(res[1]), :]
print(dom_color)
```

Alternatively, you can use Pillow's [`getcolors`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.getcolors), and get the one with the highest count:

```py
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('path/to/your/image.png')
dom_color = sorted(img.getcolors(2 ** 24), reverse=True)[0][1]
print(dom_color)
```

Both also can easily provide the second, third, ... dominant colors, if needed.

For some logo like this

[image: Logo]

the dominant color is given as :

```
[208  16  18]
```

respectively

```
(208, 16, 18)
```

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:      Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:        3.9.1
PyCharm:       2021.1.1
Matplotlib:    3.4.1
NumPy:         1.20.2
Pillow:        8.2.0
----------------------------------------
```

---

**EDIT:** Maybe, to give an adversary for the histogram approach, as also explained by Cris in the comments, see this image:

[image: Adversary]

It's hard so see, but there are three different types of red, the largest rectangle has RGB values of `(208, 0, 18)`.

Now, let's compare your histogram approach with Pillow's `getcolors`:

```py
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

adv = np.zeros((512, 512, 3), np.uint8)
adv[:200, :200, :] = [208, 16, 18]
adv[:200, 200:, :] = [208, 16, 0]
adv[200:, :200, :] = [0, 16, 18]
adv[200:, 200:, :] = [208, 0, 18]

# Histogram approach
dom_color = []
for channel_id in [0, 1, 2]:
    dom_color.append(np.argmax(np.histogram(adv[..., channel_id], bins=256, range=(0, 256))[0]))
print(dom_color)
# [208, 16, 18]

# Pillow's getcolors
dom_color = sorted(Image.fromarray(adv).getcolors(2 ** 24), reverse=True)[0][1]
print(dom_color)
# (208, 0, 18)
```

The adversary is build up to give histogram peaks at `(208, 16, 18)`. Nevertheless, the dominant color is `(208, 0, 18)` as we can easily derive from the image (or the code).